# Get pretty filenames when stripping wordpress site with wget

Tags: wordpress, wget, friendly-url

**TL;DR:** is there an option in the Wget command to strip my wordpress site with 'pretty' filenames rather than '*index.html@p=###.html*'?

I am using Wget to strip my wordpress site so I can back it up in static files on my computer. I've done this successfully with single-page sites, but this one has multiple pages. However, rather than being named after the title/URL of each page, the files are named after the page's ID number. Hence, my folder includes the following:

```
-index.html
-index.html@p=8.html
-index.html@p=14.html
```

And so on, with the format 'index.html@p=###.html' where ### is that page's ID number, instead of pretty titles like 'My Wordpress Page', etc.

I would like for the filename of each page's html file to be the page title. Is there an option in the wget command that would allow me to do that?

PS:
I did look through the entire Wget manual and did not see an option that matches that. If it does not exist, what other options are there? I am using the wget command as part of an automated process, and thus cannot manually rename them myself, and would prefer not to hard-code renaming them.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may have to write a shell script to do what you want. wget does have the -O option `wget url -O file_to_save_to`

Comment: There is very little that can be done about it. Although, I think you can use the `--trust-server-names` option here to some benefit

Comment: Thank you both. Seems like I'll have a write a shell script, though damir's suggestion does help a bit. I'll update this question if I discover anything different.  

FWIW, Jamie_D's suggestion logs the output in the file you specify.  
Damir's suggestion will save the files as index.html within the goal directory (so /about-us/index.html when I want it the eventual URL to be just /about-us), so I can probably take it from here with a shell script.  
Thanks!